# How to find absolute path of USB drive

Tags: windows, usb, path

I have a computer running Windows 8.1, and I have a USB drive with RocketDock installed. My problem is that sometimes Windows changes my drive letter and all the links on the dock screw up.

I already tried to go to Disk Management and select a drive letter, but the drive letter changes at random. Windows is not installed on the USB drive, only some of my programs.

I want to know if there's a way to get an absolute path of the device (like a mount point on Linux), so if I plug my drive in any PC it will not screw up the RocketDock links.

Here's the link for the app, if anyone finds it useful: http://rocketdock.com/

Comment: the drive letter is C? if it is, it should not change ... Oh you have installed windows in the USB drive or just rocket dock? question is not clear ... Also I dont have much information about rocket dock, can you change its links with notepad or something? can you paste a sample path/link here?

Comment: Edited it. Also, about the links, the drive letter should be assigned to D, which is the next drive letter available since I do not have a DVD drive. You can change the links on RocketDock by editing them on the program, it's just a path on the file system e.g: F:\Programs\Editor.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this from: http://www.howtogeek.com/115828/how-to-create-a-portable-version-of-rocketdock-for-a-usb-flash-drive/

> Right-click on an icon and select Icon Settings from the popup list.
>
> [image]
>
> On the Icon Settings dialog box, you’ll notice that your custom icons display in the Icons box on the right. Select the desired icon to assign that icon to the current item.
>
> The Name of the item is taken from the name of the program file, other file, or folder you placed on the dock. The Name displays below the icon when you hover your mouse over the icon. To change the name, edit the text in the Name edit box.
>
> To make the path to the executable file, other file, or folder relative, change the Target text. Remove the drive letter (e.g., “E:”) and insert “..” (without the quotes). See the image below for an example.
>
> Remove the path from the Start in edit box.
>
> Click OK to accept your changes.
>
> [image]